# Symfony 2 breadcrumbs with KnpMenu

Tags: symfony, breadcrumbs, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I use stable versions of **KnpMenu** and **KnpMenuBundle** - **v.1.2.0**
I can't use v.2, because of some dependencies.

And I'm trying to build breadcrumbs, depending on my menu.

Let's start with menu. I have my MenuBuilder class:

```
$menu = $this->factory->createItem('main');
$menu->setLabel('Main');
$menu->addChild('home', array('route' => 'home','label'=>'Home'));
$menu['home']->addChild('level1',array('route' => 'level1', 'label' => 'Level1'));
$menu['home']['level1']->addChild('level2',array('route' => 'level2', 'label' => 'Level2'));
```

The **Knp\Menu\MenuItem** class has a **getBreadcrumbsArray()** method. It should return an array of items in the current active menu trail. If you are on an earlier version of KnpMenu **(<= 1.1.2, my version)**, the returned array will be in the form of label => uri.

I guess, my breadcrumbs, when I load **level2** route should look similar to:

**Home -> Level1 -> Level2**

because Leve1 is the parent for Level2, and Home is also its ancestor.

Instead of that, **getBreadcrumbsArray()** method call in my Twig template produces following data:

```
array(2) {
  ["Main"]=>
  NULL
  ["Home"]=>
  string(25) "/symfony/web/app_dev.php/"
}
```

No **Level1**, no **Level2**, only **Home**. What is wrong? Is it supposed to work that way?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `getCurrentUri` return?

Answer (score 0):

for Knp v1, should try to that to generate childrens:

```
$menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
$menu->addChild['Main']
     ->seLabel['home']
$menu['Main']->addchild('level1', array('route', '@route1'))
$menu['Main']['level1']->addChild('level2', array('route', '@route2'))
```

```
{% knp_menu_get('Builder:BreadCrumb').getBreadcrumbsArray() %}
```